# TP4056 - Micro USB 5V 1A - Output pins Current supply

Tags: charger, nodemcu

I have "TP4056 - Micro USB 5V 1A Lithium Battery Charger with Protection" as below
[image]

I have a Li-Ion 3000mAH battery like below

[image]

Connected them as below

[image]

Questions:

1. What is the maximum current that I can get out of Output + , Output - pins.
   If I use the battery directly to my load I guess I can get up to 3Amps as battery has 1C capacity. Will it be the same from Output +- pins. In other words , are these pins just an extension of my battery (or) do they limit the current to 1 A ?
2. Can I charge the battery ( as depicted above) and also connect to the load to it at the same time.

My requirement: I am trying to power on my SIM800a module that needs 3.7 - 4.2 V and 2 A current max at some times. So I want the module to be powered using this battery , but just like we use phone, want to use it when the battery is being charged as well. I would also connect nodeMCU( D4,D3) to the SIM 800 ( Rx, Tx) to send and receive data for further implementation. At the moment I am powering my nodeMCU with another 3.3V/5V power supply, but I would want to use the same battery to it too.

Question 3: To power both of them ( sim 800a, nodeMCU) using the same battery , how should I connect them to Output pins.?

Comment: *I guess I can get up to 3Amps as battery has 1C capacity* That sentence is meaningless. The battery **capacity** (here 3 Ah) says **nothing** about the amount of current the battery can safely deliver. This figure might be listed in the datasheet of the battery. "1C" is only used as a reference to the capacity, charging at 1C would mean, charging at 3 A (I would not recommend that btw).

Comment: Also unclear: that TP4056 module, there seem to be 2 additional chips on the module, those could be for battery protection. You do not really need this as there will be protection inside that battery as well, but it does not harm to have the extra ones as well.

Comment: The module's datasheet will answer what its current limit is set to - and how to modify it if it's a decent one. The battery's datasheet will tell you the maximum continuous and short term discharge rates - either in Amps or C rating (multiply the latter by the 3Ah capacity). If you bought either without data, you know better next time.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie has a point.  The battery maximum current is first limited by the internal protection in this case and further probably limited by the board MOSFET switch.  I tried to use a similar circuit from a USB power-bank to power a small motor and the output current was limited by the in-line switch to about 1A while the direct drive 18650 type cell I used is happy to deliver a number of amps without any protection.

Comment: It is limited to 1A because the protection chip DW01KA is rated max 1A. The mosfet however can handle up to 5A.

Answer (score 0):

Your module can deliver 1.2A max. according to this [seller](http://www.dx.com/p/tp4056-4-2w-1-2a-5v-lithium-battery-charging-discharging-protection-module-w-micro-usb-blue-397213) page.

[There is](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-TP4056-4-2V-3A-High-Current-Lithium-Battery-Charging-Board-Charger-Module-M/152348735563?epid=834798867&hash=item2378b1384b:g:ZhgAAOSwnHZYSTIZ) also more powerful TP4056 modules.

Also [this](https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-Electronics-10pcs-lot-5V-Micro-USB-1A-18650-Lithium-Battery-Charging-Board-With-Protection-Charger/32495346046.html?spm=a2g10.10010108.1000016.1.553e185fo6RiEQ&isOrigTitle=true) version of your module rated at 3A for "Battery overcurrent protection current".

Comment: The module at second link is exactly the same like he already have, so I doubt this can handle 3A. The charger mosfet can handle up to 5A https://www.maritex.com.pl/product/attachment/91261/8205A.pdf however the protection IC DW01KA is rated 1A. So limit is 1A.